Das Komma und "um"
Der Satz, den ich geschrieben habe, lautete „Ich wurde unter Druck gesetzt um die Aufnahmeprüfung zu machen“, und die Korrektur sagte, dass ich „Ich wurde unter Druck gesetzt, die Aufnahmeprüfung zu machen“ schreiben könnte. Mit anderen Worten, das Komma „ersetzte“ das "um". Ist das in Ordnung? Wenn ja, warum?

Der Infinitiv hat die Funktion eines Nebensatzes, man braucht dann immer ein Komma.

Ohne sofort mit einer Erklärung zu kommen, erst mal die Beobachtung: Der "um...zu"-Satz, den du verwendet hast, ist hier grammatisch nicht gut, man braucht einen Infinitivsatz ohne "um" – zumindest für die beabsichtigte Bedeutung:

"Man setzte mich unter Druck, -?- die Prüfung zu machen" (= ich soll die Prüfung machen)
"Ich wurde unter Druck gesetzt, -?- die Prüfung zu machen." (= ich soll die Prüfung machen)

Regelmäßig ist es hier so, dass das Objekt "mich" die Einheit ist, auf die sich der Infinitiv bezieht. Wenn man das Objekt zu einem Passivsubjekt macht, ändert sich das nicht, da es mit Passiv immer noch klar ist, dass es "eigentlich" ein Objekt sein sollte. Worauf ein Infinitiv sich bezieht, hängt bei solchen Konstruktionen normalerweise vom Prädikat des Hauptsatzes ab. Zum Beispiel das Verb "jemanden bitten" verhält sich genauso wie "unter Druck setzen". Dagegen, beim Verb "versprechen" bezieht sich der Infinitiv auf das Subjekt:

Er bat mich, -?- es zu machen (= ich soll es machen)
Er versprach mir, -?- das zu machen (=er macht es).

Man muss also generell für verschiedene Verben mitlernen, in welcher Weise sie einen Infinitiv kontrollieren. So weit der Teil, der einfach und regelmäßig ist.
Jetzt die Komplikation: Interessanterweise verhält sich der "um"-Satz anders als der einfache zu-Infinitiv. Hier müsste sich der Infinitiv plötzlich auf das Subjekt beziehen:

Hans setzte mich unter Druck, um -?- die Prüfung zu machen. (= Hans will die Prüfung machen)

Diesen Satz kriegt man hin; man muss nur annehmen, dass "unter Druck setzen" für sich allein gebraucht wird, ohne anzugeben worauf der Druck abzielt; der um-Satz bezieht sich nur noch darauf dass Hans irgendwas machte, um seine Prüfung zu ermöglichen.
Das zeigt, dass zwei verschiedene Arten von Infinitivsätzen vorliegen. Daher wäre zunächst die Vermutung in Jankas Antwort plausibel, dass mit "um" ein Finalsatz, und ohne "um" ein Objektsatz vorliegt. Aber das scheint nicht zu funktionieren: Die Infinitivkonstruktion lässt sich nicht durch ein Pronomen ersetzen, auch nicht durch eine Verbindung Pronomen+Präposition (sodass wir ein Präpositionalobjekt hätten). Vergleiche:

Man setzte mich ??das / ?dazu / ?dafür unter Druck.

Hingegen geht das bei allen anderen Beispielen hier:

Man drängte mich, die Prüfung zu machen = Man drängte mich dazu.
Man bat mich darum
Man versprach es mir.

Ebensowenig kann man den Infinitiv ins Vorfeld des Satzes stellen:

?? Die Prüfung zu machen, setzten mich viele unter Druck.
Dagegen OK "Die Prüfung zu machen, drängten / baten mich viele."

Hingegen kann man den Infinitiv weglassen: "Er setzt mich unter Druck." Das geht bei den transitiven Verben "bitten, versprechen, drängen" jeweils kaum.
Das sieht für mich so aus, dass bei "unter Druck setzen" alle Infinitivkonstruktionen irgendeine Art von Finalsatz sind. Das scheint auch die Intuition zu sein, die in Irenes Frage steckt, nämlich dass das bedeutungsähnlich sein sollte. Das Unerwartete wäre nur, dass Sätze mit und ohne "um" grammatisch verschieden funktionieren.

In beiden Fällen brauchst du ein Komma nach gesetzt.
Allerdings ist die Variante mit um … zu inhaltlich subtil falsch. Da dein Hauptsatz im Passiv steht, ersetzt auch um … zu einen passiven Adverbialsatz mit damit … kann.

Ich wurde unter Druck gesetzt, um die Aufnahmeprüfung zu machen.
Ich wurde unter Druck gesetzt, damit die Aufnahmeprüfung gemacht werden kann.

Weil das beides Passiv ist, fällt nun aber das Subjekt in dem Adverbialsatz nicht mit ich zusammen. Es handelt sich um einen größeren Zusammenhang, nicht etwas, das ich macht.
Es geht also nicht um deine eigene Aufnahmeprüfung. Das ist aber nicht gemeint. In der Korrektur wird ein blanker Infinitivsatz verwendet. Dieser ersetzt nun aber einen Objektsatz, keinen Adverbialsatz:

Ich wurde unter Druck gesetzt, die Aufnahmeprüfung zu machen.
Ich wurde unter Druck gesetzt, dass ich die Aufnahmeprüfung mache.

Der Unterschied ist nun, dass dieser Objektsatz das direkte Objekt von unter Druck gesetzt werden ist, und dadurch im Objektsatz auch wieder das Subjekt ich auftaucht.
